# Selective bean loading

Tags: spring-boot

I have a library and different applications that use that library.
The problem comes that each application uses a part of the library, not all.
So how can I avoid loading the beans in the application that are not used?
thank you very much

Comment: In its current form your question leaves room for assumption and interpretation. I.e. does your library define autoconfigurations or Spring configuration classes? Are classes declared with `@Component`, `@Service` or similar annotations? Spring (Boot) allows to customize the lookup and loading behavior i.e. by redefining `@ComponentScan`, i.e. with exclusion filters, or defining your own Spring configuration where you can either define the beans you need or import existing configuration and so forth.

Comment: First of all thanks for the clarification.
The library defines configurations with the '@Configuration' annotation in different classes, in addition there are classes declared with the '@Component' annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see 3 options.

1. spring profiles (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles) -   mark your beans as activated by one or another profile and let applications define the profile to use.
2. **@ConditionalOnProperty** (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-conditionalonproperty) - mark your beans as activated by specific value of specific property and let applications define those properties.
3. A bit more complicated - turn your library into spring boot starter and define multiple auto configuration classes: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-starters

Comment: Thank you very much for the information.
I will review the proposals and try to implement it.
Greetings!